# How to make tkinter's GUI components dynamic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am making a tkinter application for Windows, and I want to make the widget placements dynamic. Like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFGK3.png), the `Label` (which is acting like a background image holder), is covering the Y-axis, but when I maximize the window, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVwm.png), the photo does not cover the whole Y-axis.

How to fix this, or is there a way to disable the windows' maximize button, without using `root.overridedirect()`?

Here is the code →

```py
#importing everything
from tkinter import *
from pypresence import Presence
import time


#making the root window
root = Tk()

dimension = (
    800,
    500
)
#setting the window
bg = PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\school 1\module\pbm\bg.png')
background = Label(root, bd=0, image=bg)
background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.geometry(f'{dimension[0]}x{dimension[1]}')


#main thing
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try `background.pack(fill="both")` instead of `background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)`

Comment: Use `root.resizable(0, 0)` to disable the `maximize` button.  Otherwise you need to resize the image whenever the root window is resized.

Comment: Step one to having a dynamic tkinter application is to use grid or pack methods rather than place.

Comment: You can disable the maximize button with `root.resizable(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by binding an event-handling function so it will be called whenever a `root` window `<Configure>` event occurs. This will allow you to change the size of the image attached the `Label` whenever the root window is moved or resized.

In the code below, the [Pillow fork](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) of the `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) is used to do the image resizing since `tkinter` doesn't provide a native way of doing it. The original image is stored separately and all scaling that needs to be done placing it on the `Label` is always relative to its size. This prevents errors from accumulating and degrading the image displayed.

Note I also changed your `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` because there was a conflict between a `tkinter.Image` and a `PIL.Image`. It's generally best to avoid `import *` prevent this from happening anyway.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import time


DIMENSION = 800, 500

def config_callback(event):
    global bg
    window_w, window_h = root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()

    # New height of image is original height * ratio of current to starting size of window.
    new_height = round(orig_height * (window_h/DIMENSION[1]))
    # Resize original image to this new size (without changing width).
    bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(orig_img.resize((orig_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    background.config(image=bg)

root = tk.Tk()

#image_path = r'C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\school 1\module\pbm\bg.png'
image_path = r'.\bkgr.png'

orig_img = Image.open(image_path)
orig_width, orig_height = orig_img.size
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(orig_img.resize((orig_width, orig_height), Image.ANTIALIAS))

background = tk.Label(root, bd=0, image=bg)
background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.geometry(f'{DIMENSION[0]}x{DIMENSION[1]}')
root.bind('<Configure>', config_callback) # Callback on window move/resize

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot showing what it looks like originally:

[image: initial screenshot]

Here's another showing what it looked like after changing the window's height:

[image: screenshot after changing window height]